# How to make a kendo-angular-datepicker to show year only

Tags: kendo-ui, typescript2.0, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-datepicker, kendo-angular-ui

How to configure the kendo-angular date picker to show year only on selecting.

Comment: @mast3rd3mon, did you look into my question. I have asked to show year only in my datepicker not the range which means i should literally show only year on pop up of datepicker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried and got the below solution, so thought of posting it if in case anyone needs:

```
<kendo-datepicker
      [min]="min"
      [max]="max"
      [bottomView]="'year'"
      [format]="'yyyy'"
      [(value)]="value"
  ></kendo-datepicker>
```

Answer (score 1):

To show year only and be able to select year only, this is what I use

```
<kendo-datepicker
    format="yyyy" <!-- Shows year only inside the textbox -->
    activeView="decade" <!-- Starting point inside the popup -->
    bottomView="decade" <!-- Can't navigate down in the popup -->
    topView="decade" <!-- Can't navigate up in the popup -->
    <!-- Add more option below as needed -->
></kendo-datepicker>
```

More info here : [Kendo DatePickerComponent API doc](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/api/DatePickerComponent/)